# Java EE Batch API add batch dynamically

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-batch

You can add batchs dynamically on a java application ee 7 batch? I.e.: upload the jar batch and application to add the new jar to the classpath and run it...

Comment: You can create jar with batch jobs xml + EJB with schedules and deploy that jar to application server

Comment: Maybe... So, i want to manage like start, stop, view status... And APP show me a job list..

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamically"?   Given that EE 7 is a standard all the application servers have capabilities to add applications without restarting the server.   What in particular are you stuck on?

Comment: a batch application has the job descriptors (META-INF / batch-jobs / xx.xml) and classes. my inicial idea was to add jobs in run-time, i mean upload a jar inside the war...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could achieve this with JBeret witch is implementation of JSR 352 provided in JBoss WildFly.

You can achieve *add batchs dynamically* simply by CDI and build jobs/batchs programatically: 
https://jberet.gitbooks.io/jberet-user-guide/content/programmatic_job_definition_with_java/index.html

To *manage like start, stop, view status* I recommend JBeret:

- https://github.com/jberet/jsr352/
- https://github.com/jberet/jberet-ui
- https://github.com/jberet/jsr352/issues/71 (screenshots)